# Can't store Files in public folder in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, database, file

i'm trying to store pdf, txt... in DB
but i get this error:

**Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateCsv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf does not exist.**

but when i add **required|mimes** this error i get:

**The file must be a file of type: pdf, xlx, csv, txt, doc.**

here the code:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,xlx,csv,txt,doc'
        ]);
        $name = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('file')->store('public/files');
        $save = new File;
        $save->name = $name;
        $save->path = $path;
        return redirect('file-upload')->with('status', 'File Has been uploaded successfully');

    }
```

my blade code:

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-4">
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-file" action="{{ url('store') }}" >
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="file" name="file" placeholder="Choose file" id="file">
                        @error('file')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                  </div>
              </div>
                
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
          </div>     
      </form>
</div>
</div>  
</body>
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use File to put content

```
\File::put(public_path('storage'). '/public/files/'. $file);
```